# How could I change string in a 2d list?

Tags: python, string, list

In Python, how could I change a string in a 2d list to 'X'?

This is the sample code.

I want to change `'9'` to `'X'`

example: `cavityMap(['1112', '1912', '1892', '1234'])`

result: `1112, 1X12, 18X2, 1234`

this is my incomplete code:

```
def cavityMap(grid):
    t = '9'

    for i, j in enumerate(grid):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        if i == len(grid)-1:
            break
        j = list(j)
        for a, b in enumerate(j):
            if b == t:
                pass

    return grid
```

Comment: Your example looks like a 1D list, for this all you you need to do is something like `mylist = [x.replace('9', 'X') for x in mylist]`

Comment: How is this code helpful? It doesn't do anything remotely like the process you're describing.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use replace function:

```
In [41]: l = ['1112', '1912', '1892', '1234']

In [42]: map_l = [x.replace('9', 'X') for x in l]

In [43]: map_l
Out[43]: ['1112', '1X12', '18X2', '1234']
```